# How to setup bootstrap validator to do not show message when an input value is not correct

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I would like to setup bootstrap validator to only show red labels when an input text is not valid or required, but I cannot remove the default message shown when the input is not valid.

I tried to force message to `message: ' '` but the default message come out anyway.

This is my code:

```
$('#myform').bootstrapValidator({
            message: ' ',
            fields: {
                nome: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that it can be done moving the `message: ' '` inside the `notEmpty`

```
$('#myform').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
            nome: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                         message: ' '
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```